# How to make Android emulator always stay on top in macOS

Tags: android, macos, window, emulation

I'm using macOS High Sierra and Android Studio 3.1, how to make the Android Studio emulator always stay on top of other windows?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can select this option in the emulator settings:

1. On the emulator's navbar select the triple-dot icon
2. Go to Settings
3. Toggle the "Emulator always on top" option

[image: Android emulator settings]

Comment: Unfortunately only works until you minimise it, then it forgets this until you turn the setting off and on again.

Comment: On Ubuntu, click to emulator "phone", hit `ALT`+ `SPACE` and select "Always on top", but yea even on Ubuntu it still resets when minimized. **however** it does not reset if you pull down the emulator window through the task bar (*not* minimize)

Comment: I don't see this option in settings

Comment: @Mr.Robot I still see it in Electric Eel (when `Launch in tool window` is disabled). which AS version are you using?